# JavaCC regex for single line comment

Tags: javacc

I am writing a lexer for a custom language and want to match a single line of comment starting with # like in python but here comment always starts from the beginning of line. Example:

`#this is a comment
and #this is not a comment`

I have tried this: "^#" (~["\n"])* ("\n")? but not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately JavaCC does not support the `^` for start of line, nor the `$` for end of line.

You can use lexical states. Use the default state `*` for the start of a line.  For example:

```
// If at the start of a line, skip a # and all other charaters on the line.
// Stay in the same state.
<*>          SKIP : { <COMMENT : "#" (~["\n"])* ("\n") > : * }

// Skip any newlines and return to (or stay in) the start of line state.
<*, MIDLINE> SKIP : { <NEWLINE : "\n" >                  : * }

// Skip any other white space.
<*, MIDLINE> SKIP : { <WHITESPACE : " " | "\t"  >        : MIDLINE }

// If not at the start of line, a # is a token.
<MIDLINE>    TOKEN : { <HASH    : "#" >                   : MIDLINE }

// Numbers can be at the start of a line or the middle of a line.
// After a number, we are no longer at the start of line.
<*, MIDLINE> TOKEN : { <NUMBER : ["0"-"9"]+ >            : MIDLINE }
```

and so on.